# Mobile browser datetime-local input field text align issue

Tags: html, cordova, datetimepicker

I have an issue with `<input type="datetime-local"/>`  If I add the `style="text-align:right;"` attribute to it, it appears that it does not align the datetime value to the right.  In the image below taken from my iPad, you can see how this is displayed incorrectly.  When I look at the same page on the browser on a PC, the text is aligned right just like I would expect.  Is there some special mobile property for CSS to get this looking the way I want?

I would like to add that simply using float:right will not solve my issue as I am making a customizable generic popover menu that allows all the standard ios input fields you can see in a native app (like apple's "Calendar" app).  This means that I need the calendar picker popover to show up when the user does a "click" or "tap" event anywhere in the li.

Here is how it currently looks on the iPad, with similar results on android:

[image: DateTime not aligned to right]

Comment: I figured out how to get the same functionality using the "click" event on the li and using .focus() on the datefield and moving the datetime-local field to the right.  I am still interested in an answer for the question though.